# Multithreading IOS concepts to explore

Tags: ios, multithreading, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, block

i am working in a very complex application in which,i need to improve the performance.
i have keen interest in Multithreading and have studied docs of GCD and Blocks.
Although, i have improved the performance quite a bit.
i am searching for few answers :-

1. We have global queue in iOS -> how to check what other tasks they execute or these are vacant queue made for us to use.
2. If we make our custom queue

   - what priority it has wrt already existing global concurrent queues.
   - How we can set priority of our custom queue, if we make >2.
3. If we make custom serial/concurrent queues -> how to set priority statically or dynamically if possible.

Thanks, if anybody has answers...